# Como apresentar o nome do cliente de determinada venda? não estou conseguindo buscar o nome com o get

Tags: php, mysql

codigo da lista de vendas que estou com problema para apresentar o nome do cliente de cada venda e nome do produto de cada venda tbm! não sei o que estou fazendo de errado

```
<?php
  include_once("Sessao.php");
  include_once("Valida.php");
  include_once("Cabecalho.php");

 include_once './Classes/Singleton.php';

 include_once './Classes/Venda.php';
 include_once './Classes/VendaDao.php';

 // include_once 'Classes/Cliente.php';
 // include_once 'Classes/ClienteDao.php';
// include_once 'Classes/Produto.php';
// include_once 'Classes/ProdutoDao.php';?>

<?php 
    if($_GET && $_GET["msg"] && $_GET["tpMsg"]){
 ?>
    <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $_GET["tpMsg"] ?>" role="alert">
        <strong>Atenção: </strong><?php echo $_GET["msg"]?>
    </div>
<?php 
    }
 ?>

<div>   
   <a class="btn btn-success" href="FormVenda.php"> Novo Venda </a>
</div>

   <hr>

 <div>
   <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Código </th>
            <th> Data </th>
            <th> Cliente </th>
            <th> Produto </th>
            <th> Quantidade </th>                
            <th> Preço </th>                
            <th> Total </th>                
            <th> Ações </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php

        $vendaDao = new VendaDao();
        $lista = $vendaDao->listar();

        foreach ($lista as $venda) {

            //$urlAlterar = "FormVenda.php?comando=U&codigo={$venda->getCodigo()}";
            $urlExcluir = "FormVenda.php?comando=D&codigo={$venda->getCodigo()}";
            $urlExcluir = "JavaScript:if(confirm('Deseja realmente excluir o venda?')) { document.location.href='{$urlExcluir}' }";

            echo
            "<tr>
                <td> {$venda->getCodigo()} </td>
                <td> {$venda->getData()} </td>
                <td> {$venda->getCliente()->getNome()} </td>
                <td> {$venda->getProduto()->getNome()} </td>
                <td> {$venda->getQuantidade()} </td>

                <td>
                    <a class='btn btn-danger' href=\"{$urlExcluir}\"> Excluir </a>
                </td>
            </tr>";
        }

        ?>

    </tbody>
</table>

 </div>
    <!-- <td> R$ {$venda->getProduto()->getPreco()} </td>
   <td> R$ " . ($venda->getPreco() * $venda->getQuantidade()) . " </td> -->
```

```
<?php

class VendaDao {

    private $pdo = null;

    public function __construct(){
        //pegar instancia e atribuir $pdo

        $this->pdo = Singleton::getInstance()->getPDO();
    }


    public function salvar(Venda $venda){
        //aqui dentro sempre vira um objeto

        if( !$venda->getCodigo() ){

            $sql = "INSERT INTO venda(data, quantidade, cliente, produto)
            VALUES(:data, :quantidade, :cliente, :produto)";

             $resultado = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        } else {

             $sql = "UPDATE venda SET data=:data, quantidade=:quantidade, cliente=:cliente,
                 produto=:produto WHERE codigo=:codigo";

             $resultado = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
             $resultado->bindValue(":codigo",$venda->getCodigo(),PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }

            $resultado->bindValue(":data",$venda->getData(),PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $resultado->bindValue(":quantidade",$venda->getQuantidade(),PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $resultado->bindValue(":cliente",$venda->getCliente(),PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $resultado->bindValue(":produto",$venda->getProduto(),PDO::PARAM_INT);

                 $resultado->execute();
    }


    public function excluir($codigo){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM venda WHERE codigo=:codigo";
        $resultado = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $resultado->bindValue(":codigo",$codigo,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $resultado->execute();

        return $resultado->rowCount() ==1;

    }

    public function listar(){
        $vendas = array();



        $sql = "SELECT codigo, data, quantidade, cliente, produto, 'c.nome', 'p.nome' FROM venda as v 
        INNER JOIN cliente c ON 'c.codigoCli' = 'v.cliente' 
        INNER JOIN produto p ON 'p.codigoPro' = 'v.produto' 
        ORDER BY data";
        $resultado = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $resultado->execute();

        while( $vendaBD = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ){

            $venda = new Venda();
            $venda->setCodigo($vendaBD->codigo);
            $venda->setData($vendaBD->data);
            $venda->setQuantidade($vendaBD->quantidade);

            $c = new Cliente();
            $c->setCodigoCli($vendaBD->codigoCli);
            $c->setNome($vendaBD->nome);
            $venda->setCliente($c);

            $p = new Produto();
            $p->setCodigoPro($vendaBD->codigoPro);
            $p->setNome($vendaBD->nome);
            $venda->setProduto($p);


        $vendas[] = $venda;
        print_r($vendas);

   }

        return $vendas;


        }
  }


 ?>
```

Comment: Pode mostrar o código fonte do `VendaDao()`?

Comment: Bem vinda ao Stack Overflow Amanda! Prefira postar o código em texto, assim fica mais fácil para alguém que quer responder reproduzir seu problema.

Comment: Você pode mostrar o código da classe da sua Venda.

Comment: No lugar do nome vem o código?

Comment: sim aparece o codigo do cliente mas não o nome

Comment: Quando vc chama `getCliente()` aparece o que?

Comment: quando eu chamo getCliente() aparece o codigo do cliente e quando coloco na frente getNome() da erro

Comment: Qual erro aparece?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getNome() on a non-object

Comment: editei o código da resposta.

Comment: Seu usuário tem nome no banco de dados? Porque se está dando erro, é porque não existe uma instância do nome.

Comment: O que acontece quando você faz um `var_dump($venda);` dentro do seu `foreach()`?

Comment: tente algo do tipo: `get_class_methods ( $venda );`

Answer (score 1):

O problema parece ser sua tabela `venda` os campos `cliente` e `produto` não são descrições como joão e café, são ids por isso ao chamar `getCliente()` um número é exibido.

Para corrigir isso é necessario fazer dois joins um para cliente e outro para produto para obter suas descrições. Caso os campos tenham os mesmo nomes em tabelas diferentes use um alias para evitar sobrescrita de valores no php.

Feito isso basta criar os objetos cliente e produto e setar seus repectivos valores.

Sua consulta deve ficar mais ou menos dessa forma, adeque os nomes dos campos.

```
SELECT codigo, data, quantidade, cliente, produto,
       c.nome as nome_cliente, p.nome as nome_produto
    FROM venda as v 
    INNER JOIN cliente c ON c.codigoCli = v.cliente
    INNER JOIN produto p ON p.codigoPro = v.produto 
ORDER BY dat
```

Agora no while crie o objeto cliente e produto

```
while( $vendaBD = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ){

    $venda = new venda();
    $venda->setCodigo($vendaBD->codigo);
    $venda->setData($vendaBD->data);
    $venda->setQuantidade($vendaBD->quantidade);

    $c = new Cliente();
    $c->setId($vendaBD->cliente);
    $c->setNome($vendaBD->nome_cliente);

    $venda->setCliente($c);

    $p = new Produto();
    $p->setId($vendaBD->produto);
    $p->setNomeProduto($vendaBD->nome_produto);
    $venda->setProduto($p);


    $vendas[] = $venda;
}
return $vendas;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que estou vendo o erro é mais banal do que parece. Você está colocando aspas e não tem que colocar isso na sua query de consulta e testa usando mesmo nome para produto e para nome, neste caso, crie um **alias**. Faça conforme abaixo:

```
 $sql = "SELECT 
          codigo,
          data,
          quantidade,
          cliente,
          produto,
          IF(c.nome == NULL,'Nome não informado',c.nome) as nome,
          IF(p.nome == NULL,'Nome do produto não informado',c.nome) as nome_produto
        FROM venda as v 
        INNER JOIN cliente c ON (c.codigoCli = v.cliente) 
        INNER JOIN produto p ON (p.codigoPro = v.produto) 
        ORDER BY data";
```

Troque o campo **data** para **data_reg**, assim você evita erros de SQL, pois a palavra **data** é reservada do MySQL.

**OBS:** Quando você coloca aspas no campo tipo: 'c.nome', é o mesmo que dizer que você construiu um valor string "c.nome", e não que o seu campo se chama nome. Porém você pode colocar aspas no seu alias, pois se trata de uma associação de nome, e principalmente quando o alias exige um espaço. Algo como `Select c.nome AS 'Nome de Usuário' from tabela`. Também poderia criar um campo fictício desta mesma maneira colocando um valor tipo: `SELECT 0 as Zero from tabela`, ou `SELECT 'Amanda' as Nome from tabela`, que ele criaria a a coluna Zero com valor 0 e criaria a coluna Nome com valor Amanda.

E onde você seta o nome do produto, você tem que alterar com a chamada do alias:

```
$p->setNome($vendaBD->nome_produto);
```

Comment: vou tentar! Obrigada deve ser isto msm

Comment: então, eu coloco aspas pq sem elas da erro falando que não encontra a classe cliente dai eu coloquei e não da mais o erro só não lista

Comment: Então, então entendeu porque não dá erro? Porque vc está preenchendo o campo com um valor fake.

Comment: Troca o campo data e veja se vai parar o problema.

Comment: sim, entendi! vou trocar

Comment: Faz um teste, só executa isso no workbench ou phpmyadmin: `select 'a.nome' as Nome`; ou `select 'a.nome' as 'Nome do cara'`;

Comment: Outra coisa, como vc mudou o alias, agora você tem que chamar ele no lugar.   `$p->setNome($vendaBD->nome_produto);`

Comment: Vou faze uma pequena edição, para que sua instância nunca retorne com erro caso não exista um valor em um dos campos.

Comment: Consegui!! eu tirei as aspas e coloquei alias como vc falou e funcionou. Muito obrigada pela ajuda